# Very slow processing in Apache-Beam for BigQuery operations

Tags: python, google-bigquery, apache-beam

Using `beam.io.WriteToBigQuery` and `beam.io.BigQuerySource`

How large is the very large dataset that apache-beam can't handle without partitioning?

They mentioned in the official website :

> If you are using the Beam SDK for Python, you might have import size quota issues if you write a very large dataset [source](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/)

which are really confusing! I have 100,000 row of data in one BigQuery table, and I don't think that is `very large`?

But I am facing very high latency when read the data and write it again to other table in BigQuery.